# How can i add audio to a listView?

Tags: java, android, listview

The Error i get is

> cannot resolve method create(anonymous
>   android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, int)'

I Underlined the code

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, socialArrayPhrases);
    socialPhrases.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    socialPhrases.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position_of_phrase, long ld) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),socialArrayPhrases.get(position_of_phrase) ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(position_of_phrase == 0)
                {
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test_audio);
                   -----------------------------------------------------------
                }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use encapsulating class name with `this`.

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(EncapulatingClassWithContext.this, R.raw.test_audio);
```

Could be a `Fragment` or an `Activity`.

Comment: The worst thing that you can say in these situations is it didn't work. Never forget to add what/how it didn't work. Was there some other error? If yes then post the error message/description.

Comment: Apologies. It says cannot resolve EncapulatingClassWithContext.this

Comment: EncapulatingClassWithContext is not a real name of the class. It is a class name that was self-explanatory, maybe (in your case) an `Activity` or a `Fragment`, other classes can also provide `Context`. What you need to do is provide a `Context` from the `Activity` to create the `MediaPlayer`. You should be passing your Activity's reference. Whatever that is.

Comment: such as MainACtivity.this?

Comment: I have tried what you told me. No errors but audio doesn't play or make a sound. I tried the audio outside Android Studio and it works.

Comment: See the logs for a media player error then, or set an Error Listener, you are probably not starting the playback on `MediaPlayer`. If you are then chances are there's an error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your first parameter is of type, It is expected to be context. You might be passing of type of adapter or fragment.

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test_audio); //This is not type of context
```

To quickly validate replace null with this and see

Comment: it removed the error, but now when the app runs it stops it doesn't play the audio

Comment: I am trying to be able to when i click on an item in ListvIew each one plays an audio